# How to separate the three phases in the attached image(SE or BSE)?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-manipulation, image-segmentation, imagej

Visually I can see the difference between all phases, one is black (that is pore), and other two are two kind of particle with different texture and brightness.

How to separate these three phases ? If anyone could suggest something that will be great help. Thank you.

I tried to separate using image histogram, but it's not working.

[image: sample_BSE image]
[image: sample_SE image]

Comment: you can try some simple threshold techniques

Comment: I can not see the diferences, can you clearly show them?

Comment: Hi Ander, if you notice in BSE image of sample, more bright points are the one phase particles and others are not so bright. And for the same sample in SE image the texture of two phases are completely different one phase is separated particles and other is continuous fluid kind of phase. So visually, I can identify each particle,  but in imagej or matlab thresholding only considers on basis of brightness of pixels so I couldn't do it. Any other tecniques or idea if you can suggest that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Jeru, simple thresholding doesn't work. Pores can be separated by simple thresholding but not the other phases in sample.

Comment: @AnderBiguri            can we threshold on any other basis besides of brightness, please check last comment

Comment: Of course, you can use any criteria with thresholding, but the tricky thing is defining a good one, which separates the different parts as clearly as possible.

Comment: Can you provide us the code of what you have tried so far, such as _thresholding the brightness_? Why do you think it will not work, as you mentioned in your question they have a different brightness?

Comment: It may be useful to provide some ground truth (by segmenting it manually), so everyone knows what the output should be.

Comment: I have tried all available thresholding criteria available in ImageJ and also tried to threshold manually by varying the gray intensity over the range of 0-255 but couldn't get clear separation of phases on basis of brightness. Is there any other criteria like texture or something on which I can separate the phases ? @m7913d

Comment: You can try to calculate the fourier spectrum locally (see `fft2`). Note that I'm not sure it will give good results, because the pattern does not seems to be that different. Note that a ground truth and your best, but not yet optimal segmentation code may be really helpful.

Comment: A very similar topic has been discussed on the **ImageJ forum** in [this thread](http://forum.imagej.net/t/triple-phase-points-in-image-or-pattern-matching/5391?u=imagejan), so I'm linking to it here in case someone finds it useful.